# Segmentation fault and MPI

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, matrix-multiplication

In my program I need to do some matrix multiplication using MPI.
When I run my program, I get the following error:

```
=====================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
=====================================================================================
APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

It executes:

```
 printf("Sent a\n");
```

The error is in:

```
 MPI_Send(&b, nColA*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

It doesn't execute:

```
 printf("Sent b\n");
```

I don't now why.

Can you help me?

```
void multiplicaMatriz (int taskid, int numtasks, float **a, float **b, float **c, long int nLinA, long int nColA, long int nLinB, long int nColB)
{
    long int    i, j, k, rc;           /* misc */

    int numworkers,        /* number of worker tasks */
    source,                /* task id of message source */
    dest,                  /* task id of message destination */
    mtype,                 /* message type */
    rows,                  /* rows of matrix A sent to each worker */
    averow, extra, offset; /* used to determine rows sent to each worker */

    MPI_Status status;

    numworkers = numtasks-1;


   /**************************** master task ************************************/
   if (taskid == MASTER)
   {
      printf("mpi_mm has started with %d tasks.\n",numtasks);

      /* Send matrix data to the worker tasks */
      averow = nLinA/numworkers;
      extra = nLinA%numworkers;
      offset = 0;
      mtype = FROM_MASTER;
      for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++)
      {
         rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow;    
         printf("Sending %d rows to task %d offset=%d\n",rows,dest,offset);
         MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Sent offset %d\n", offset);
         MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Sent rows %d\n", rows);
         MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows*nColA, MPI_FLOAT, dest, mtype,
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Sent a\n");          
         MPI_Send(&b, nColA*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         printf("Sent b\n");
         offset = offset + rows;
      }

      /* Receive results from worker tasks */
      mtype = FROM_WORKER;
      for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++)
      {
         source = i;
         MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], rows*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, source, mtype, 
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         printf("Received results from task %d\n",source);
      }

      /* Print results */
      printf("******************************************************\n");
      printf("Result Matrix:\n");
      for (i=0; i<nLinA; i++)
      {
         printf("\n"); 
         for (j=0; j<nColB; j++) 
            printf("%6.2f   ", c[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n******************************************************\n");
      printf ("Done.\n");
   }


   /**************************** worker task ************************************/
   if (taskid > MASTER)
   {
      mtype = FROM_MASTER;
      MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&a, rows*nColA, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Recv(&b, nColA*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      for (k=0; k<nColB; k++)
         for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
         {
            c[i][k] = 0.0;
            for (j=0; j<nColA; j++)
               c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
         }
      mtype = FROM_WORKER;
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&c, rows*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
 }
```

Comment: how I use the debugger? I don't now use the debugger.

Comment: now is the time to learn....

Comment: I'm programming an algorithm that has four matrix multiplication. This algorithm is correct for sequential approach and I need to use MPI now. There is a function to multiply two matrixes. A will use MPI only in this function. I show yours only this function where I included the two firsts variables: taskid and numtasks. I don't know  use debugger then, I put "printf" to find where is the error, and it is in the line that I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to accessing `b` incorrectly.

Read this declaration carefully:

```
int MPI_Send(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm);
```

If you look at the `buf` parameter, it's a `void*` which gets cast as whatever type `datatype` is. When you call `MPI_Send(&b, nColA*nColB, MPI_FLOAT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`, you're passing `&b`. This is a reference to `b`, which has type `float***`. The function treats this as if it's type `float*`, causing the error.

In your other calls to `MPI_Send()` you pass `&a[offset][0]`, which *does* have the correct type of `float*`. Try passing `&b[offset][0]`, or however you need to order those array indices to get the multiplication to come out right.

I'm not going to go through the labor of finding out these indices for you, that's your job. But this is what's causing the segfault.

Comment: It's ok. nColA must be equal nRowB. I changed and the error continues.

Comment: That makes sense, since you're doing matrix multiplication. How are you calling the function `multiplicaMatriz()`? You could be passing something incorrectly. You have a lot of parameters to that function; make sure the values you pass to it when you call it are in the correct order. Double check this!

Comment: I did. I printed all dimensions of the matrix and they are corrects.

Comment: I did it too. I need to pass all b matrix, then I put &b[0][0] and the error continues.

Comment: Like I said, there's only so much help I can give you! You'll have to work out what these indices should be. Look up examples online, it's easy to find a half a dozen source files.